# What happens to array values after replacing them in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, memory

I would like to know, if the values of an array (of any type) are automatically nilled, when I replace them with another one. For example the first value of an UIImage-Array is replaced with another image. What happens to that first image, that the array previously contained? Is only the reference removed or the image itself from the RAM?

Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concept of ARC is to be used here.
First image is also a UIImage instance, and when you replace first UIImage object with second UIImage object, the strong reference to the first object is removed.
CASE 1: (Now, I assume that you have not used that first UIImage instance in any other line or assigned to any other variables.)
since, the object doesn't have any strong reference to it. ARC automatically removes it from memory as the instant you replace it with second image's object.

CASE 2: BUT If you have assigned it to next variable also then it won't be deleted.
let me demonstrate you with example:

---

CASE 1:

```
var images = [UIImage]()
images.append(UIImage(named: "elcapitan"))
//now this first image is stored in index number 0 of the array
//images[0] gives you access to this first image in this case

//now i will replace the first image
images[0] = UIImage(named: "yosemite")
```

In this case the ARC automatically removes first image instance because it is not strong referenced from anywhere

---

Case 2:

```
var images = [UIImage]()
var firstImage = UIImage(named: "elcapitan")
images.append(firstImage)
//now this first image is stored in index number 0 of the array
//images[0] gives you access to this first image in this case

//now i will replace the first image
images[0] = UIImage(named: "yosemite")
```

In this case the ARC can't remove first image instance because it is still strong referenced by variable firstImage though you have replaced in array. the instance will be removed only after you assign next image to firstImage variable. i.e. only if you do like this: firstImage = UIImage(name: "Windows")

HOPE YOU GOT YOU ANSWER :)

Answer (score 3):

The image will only be released when there are no more references to it.

Take a look at [Automatic Reference Counting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Swift uses Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). And you must keep in mind the difference between classes and structures in swift.

From Apple's documentation:

> Reference counting only applies to instances of classes. Structures and enumerations are value types, not reference types, and are not stored and passed by reference.

Briefly, ARC keeps track of how many constants, variables and properties are referencing (strong reference) an instance of a class. If there are no references, ARC deallocates the instance and frees up memory.

```
class Person {
   var name: String

   init(name: String) {
     self.name = name
   }
}

var steve: Person? = Person(name: "Steve") // Increasing ref counter -> 1
var sameSteve: Person? = steve // Increasing ref counter -> 2

steve = nil // Decreasing ref counter -> 1

print(sameSteve?.name) // prints "Steve"

sameSteve = nil // Decreasing ref counter -> 1

print(sameSteve?.name) // prints nil because it was deallocated
```

So, as `UIImage` is a reference type, if removed from an array or replaced, ARC will decrease its reference counter. If no other variable, constant or property is holding it, the image will be deallocated.